# Generating survival and censoring times from proportional hazards model

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.07758.pdf) where, on the page 13, the authors state that the survival times $T_i$ are generated from a proportional hazards (PH) model with hazard function:

$$\lambda_T(t\mid X_i, W_i)=\exp(\beta X_{i1}+(-0.5-\gamma_1 X_{i2})W_i)\sqrt{t}/2$$

where $W_i$ is the treatment assignment. The censoring times are generated from a Weibull distribution with hazard function $\kappa^\rho$ where $\kappa$ is the scale parameter and $\rho$ is the shape parameter. In the supplementary code for the paper, the survival times are generated as

```
survival.time <- (-log(runif(n)) / exp(beta * X[ ,1] + (-0.5 - gamma * X[ ,2]) * W))^2
```

and the censoring times are generated as

```
    censor.time <- (-log(runif(n)) / (kappa ^ rho)) ^ (1 / rho)
```

However, the parameterization the authors are using doesn't seem to be consistent with [existing approaches](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3546387/) for generating survival times from PH models so I'm not sure where these lines of code are coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion might come from the [multiple parameterizations of the Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Alternative_parameterizations). Note that the first hazard function can be written in the form $\lambda(t)=\lambda_0(t) \exp(\eta_i)$, where $\eta_i$ is the linear predictor for individual $i$ and $\lambda_0(t)=\sqrt t/2$. With the baseline hazard $\lambda_0(t)$ proportional to a power of $t$, as for a Weibull hazard, that's a proportional-hazards representation of a Weibull survival model. Thus the hazards both for the survival and for the censoring are based on Weibull models.

In the parameterization used in the [Austin paper you cite](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3546387/), the Weibull *cumulative* hazard is represented as $H_0(t)=\lambda t^{\nu}$ and you simulate a Weibull-distributed survival time $T$ by sampling $u$ from a uniform distribution of survival fractions over (0,1) and calculating:

$$T = \left(-\frac{\log u}{\lambda \exp (\eta)} \right)^{1/\nu} .$$

That comes from the general relationship between the survival function $S(t)$ and the cumulative hazard function, $S(t)=\exp(-H(t))$. Both examples of simulation code that you show are in that general form for simulation from a Weibull survival model, although I can't rule out some discrepancies in the translation from page 13 of the [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.07758.pdf) to the supplementary code arising from the differing parameterizations.